# avoid each row stored in multiple times into mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

Here i'm trying to validate and insert the registration details into database using ajax concept. I've tried below coding. Below coding successfully inserted the details into database and then it show the error messages too.

My question is -> For example, Assume if user didn't enter the lastname and email fields. User enter the firstname only and then hit the submit button. Now, i'm getting the error message (Last Name Required). Again user filled remaining fields and hit the submit button. When i check the database table i'm getting two rows (it should be one row). Problem is it could store the datas multiple times (depending on how many times the submit button pressed - if user get validation error message 5 times the same row stored in 5 times, if user get validation error message 3 times the same row stored in 3 times )

How to avoid the one row stored in mutiple times?

### ajax.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#simple-post").click(function() {
        jQuery("#ajaxform").submit(function(e) {
            jQuery("#simple-msg").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax( {
                url : 'validation.php',
                type: "POST",
                data :  $('form').serialize(),
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    jQuery("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();  //STOP default action
        });

        $("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
    });

});
```

### mainpage.php

```
<form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" >
  First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /> <br/>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /> <br/>
  Email : <input type="text" name="email" /> <br/>
  <input type="button"  id="simple-post" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

### validation.php

```
<?php

    include_once('config.php');

    $name = trim($_POST["fname"]);
    $mobile = trim($_POST["lname"]);
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);

    if($name == "")
    {
        echo 'First Name required';
        die();
    }
    if($mobile == "")
    {
        echo 'Last Name Required';
        die();
    }
    if($email == "")
    {
        echo 'Email required';
        die();
    }

    try
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sample ( Name, Mobile, Email ) VALUES ( ?, ?, ? )");
        $conn->errorInfo();
        $stmt->bindParam('1', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('2', $mobile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam('3', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        echo 'inserted succesfully';
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'failed to insert ' .$e->getMEssage();
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#simple-post").click(function() {

            jQuery("#simple-msg").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax( {
                url : 'validation.php',
                type: "POST",
                data :  $('form').serialize(),
                success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    jQuery("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');

                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
                {
                    $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();  //STOP default action
        });

});
```

Submit the form within the success handler of your validation AJAX call, not unconditional outside.

And, additionally, you don't need a submit handler at all. Once the user clicks the button, validate the form and on success the data will be in the database already.

Comment: That will create an infinite loop. The submit handler calls AJAX, and when it returns it submits again.

Comment: Look at his PHP. The validation is done on the server, in the AJAX submission handler.

Comment: ok, then he even doesn't need to submit it since on success the data is already all in.

Comment: @AxelAmthor : I tried this one. its working... Thanks. i'm new to ajax so its diffucult to understand ajax..

Comment: @AxelAmthor : i have a another doubt.. i'm getting the validation error messages in bottom of the page `<div id="simple-msg"></div>`. i want these error message should be appear on the appropriate field row.. how to do that?

Comment: In this case, your `validation.php` should be a bit more chatty about what has actually happened and not just only "dying". Pass an ID back as JSON for the erroneous field and use that to insert the message at the div with that id. Sample: `echo '{"field":"email", "message":"Email required" }';`

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click on the submit button, you're binding another `submit` handler to to the form. So when the form is submitted, all these handlers run, and they each create another row in the database. You should bind the submit handler just once, outside the `click` handler.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#simple-post").click(function() {
        $("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
    });
    jQuery("#ajaxform").submit(function(e) {
        jQuery("#simple-msg").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
        $.ajax( {
            url : 'validation.php',
            type: "POST",
            data :  $('form').serialize(),
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                jQuery("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">'+data+'</code></pre>');
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint">AJAX Request Failed<br/> textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</code></pre>');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();  //STOP default action
    });
});
```

There's also no need for the click handler on the submit button -- the default behavior of clicking on a submit button is to trigger the form's `submit` event.

Comment: i tried this one. but its not working.. i didn't get any validation error messages and it didn't insert the datas into db..

Comment: Is it displaying the loading image?

Comment: Get rid of the click handler. I think it's invoking the default submit action, not your jQuery handler.